# Group by en consulta sql server cuando hay valores null

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una consulta SQL que no logro agrupar.
Lo que necesito es una sola linea por día. Actualmente como lo tengo es que la consulta me trae dos lineas, trato de agrupar pero no he tenido éxito.

```
select a.claveemp, a.nombre, a.fecha, a.nomb_dia, a.EntradaProgramada,a.SalidaProgramada,a.EntradaReal,a.SalidaReal
from(
SELECT
    empleado.claveemp,
    empleado.nombre,
    horario.fecha,
    horario.nomb_dia
    ,case
        when cve_movto_horario in ('1')
        then horario_deta.hora_prog
        end AS EntradaProgramada,
    case
        when cve_movto_horario in ('8')
        then horario_deta.hora_prog
        end AS SalidaProgramada,
    case
        when cve_movto_horario in ('1')
        then horario_deta.hora_regi
        end AS EntradaReal,
    case
        when cve_movto_horario in ('8')
        then horario_deta.hora_regi
        end AS SalidaReal
FROM
    horario_deta
INNER JOIN horario
ON horario_deta.id_horario = horario.id_horario
INNER JOIN horario_resumen
ON horario.semana = horario_resumen.semana AND horario.anio = horario_resumen.anio AND horario.claveemp = horario_resumen.claveemp
INNER JOIN empleado
on replace(ltrim(replace(horario.claveemp,'0',' ')),' ','0') =  replace(ltrim(replace(empleado.claveemp,'0',' ')),' ','0') and horario.anio >= '2021'
WHERE
cve_movto_horario in (1,8)
) a
WHERE
a.claveemp = '602056' and a.fecha between '2022-08-01' and '2022-08-15'
group by 
a.claveemp, a.nombre, a.fecha, a.nomb_dia,  a.EntradaProgramada,a.SalidaProgramada,a.EntradaReal,a.SalidaReal
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esta es la forma en que lo hice, igual si existe alguna otra forma estoy abierto comentarios.

Gracias por sus comentarios.

Comment: deberias agrupar la consulta interna primero, para que esa devuelva una fila por persona...

Comment: lo he hecho afuera y adentro y el resultado ha sido el mismo.

Comment: y lograste que la consulta interna devolviera una sola fila? porque ahi es donde tenes que trabajar. La consulta ahora te devuelve 2 registros, uno para salidas y otro para entradas... eso es lo que tenes que planchar.. usando max ;)

Comment: si intente con MAX pero sin exito

Comment: y como lo intentaste? si haces un fiddle con la consulta interna puedo ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás agrupando por todas las columnas y por eso no agrupa absolutamente nada. También hay otros problemas menores como el hecho de tener una subconsulta innecesaria o condiciones fuera de lugar y la limpieza de la clave de empleado en el JOIN (esa es más grave pero no es el lugar para corregirla).

Para poder condensar las filas y tener una sola por empleado y fecha, necesitas usar funciones de agregación.

```
SELECT
    e.claveemp,
    e.nombre,
    h.fecha,
    h.nomb_dia,
    MAX( CASE WHEN cve_movto_horario = 1 THEN hd.hora_prog END) AS EntradaProgramada,
    MAX( CASE WHEN cve_movto_horario = 8 THEN hd.hora_prog END) AS SalidaProgramada,
    MAX( CASE WHEN cve_movto_horario = 1 THEN hd.hora_regi END) AS EntradaReal,
    MAX( CASE WHEN cve_movto_horario = 8 THEN hd.hora_regi END) AS SalidaReal
FROM       horario_deta    hd
INNER JOIN horario         h  ON hd.id_horario = h.id_horario
INNER JOIN horario_resumen hr ON h.semana = hr.semana AND h.anio = hr.anio AND h.claveemp = hr.claveemp
INNER JOIN empleado        e  ON REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(h.claveemp,'0',' ')),' ','0') =  REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(e.claveemp,'0',' ')),' ','0') 
WHERE cve_movto_horario in (1,8)
AND   h.anio >= '2021'
AND   h.claveemp = '602056' 
AND   h.fecha between '2022-08-01' and '2022-08-15'
GROUP BY e.claveemp,
         e.nombre,
         h.fecha,
         h.nomb_dia;
```

Comment: si gracias, justo así lo resolví